# Apache PDFBox rotate PDImageXObject

Tags: java, pdf, matrix, transformation, pdfbox

I'm playing around with the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, and I want to set the page to landscape and also rotate my picture.  So I've done `page.setRotation(90);`

There seems to be a bug with using PDFBox and AffineTransform

This code doesn't do anything like I'd expect:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(w, 0, 0, h, 20, 20);
at.translate(0.5, 1);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
```

Width and Height have to be tiny to keep the image on the page, rotate by itself squishes the image, and translate before rotate seems to scale the image huge.

Is this a bug, or am I just not understanding PDFBox?

Comment: So you create a transformation matrix. But how do you use it? And what effect do you expect your transformation values to have?

Comment: As per my first sentence: "I want to set the page to landscape and also rotate my picture".  But both translate and rotate are having ridiculous scaling effects.

Comment: @djb: I've updated my answer. I didn't test the 90° page rotation yesterday, and when using it, I got the effect you described.

Comment: @djb It generally is helpful if the sample code provided in question can easily be used to reproduce the issue. You only present code for setting page rotation and generating an affine transformation but not how you use that affine transformation. Tilman bothered to write such code, others didn't. If you had provided the code, you may well have gotten more replies.

Comment: @mkl - I actually did have the original rotation code, and Tilman asked me to clean up my question.  The rotation code rotated it off the screen somewhere, so the example I've left behind just shows the weird bugs I've described.

Comment: @djb ;) Ok, you never can please everybody.

Comment: I asked the cleanup because it was unclear to me what part of the code was used. Anyway, if none of the two answers is helpful, please upload the image you need to place on the PDF. If it is confidential, please upload a non confidential image of the same size, and tell where you like the image to appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do an extra translation, instead put the translation when creating the AT. Remember that the rotation is around the bottom-left axis, so add the width w to the x-position.

```
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    page.setRotation(90);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    int x = 150;
    int y = 300;

    // draw unrotated
    contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, x, y, ximage.getWidth() / 2, ximage.getHeight() / 2);

    // draw 90° rotated, placed on the right of the first image
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(ximage.getHeight() / 2, 0, 0, ximage.getWidth() / 2, x + ximage1.getWidth(), y);
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
    contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, at);
```

This will draw the image twice, once normally and once rotated 90°, and positioned to the right. "/2" is used to scale 50%, you can of course use another factor. Note that "/2" is not used for the initial x position, because the (scaled) width is needed twice. Once to position to the old position (because of the axis!), and once to move it to the right so that the images don't overlap.

Note also that getHeight() and getWidth() are reversed, for the page rotation.

Comment: Ah ha, I worked it out.  You almost had it though.  This is the trick:
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(ximage.getWidth() / 2, 0, 0, ximage.getHeight() / 2, x + ximage1.getWidth(), y);

Answer (score 2):

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(w, 0, 0, h, 20, 20);
at.translate(0.5, 1);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
```

> Width and Height have to be tiny to keep the image on the page, rotate by itself squishes the image, and translate before rotate seems to scale the image huge.
>
> Is this a bug, or am I just not understanding PDFBox?

It is not a bug, it simply is math. You merely have to be aware that if you have an `AffineTransform at` and then call `at.translate(...)` or `at.rotate(...)`, you do not *set the translation / rotation part* of the affine transformation to the given values but instead replace your transformation by the *composition of the former transformation and the translation / rotation*.

This means that e.g.

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(w, 0, 0, h, 20, 20);
at.translate(0.5, 1);
```

is **not the same as**

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(w, 0, 0, h, 20.5, 21);
```

as you might have expected, but **instead**

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(w, 0, 0, h, 20 + w/2, 20 + h);
```

This is why *Width and Height have to be tiny to keep the image on the page* - `translate(0.5, 1)` pushes very far otherwise.

As the order in which you compose the transformation matters, you might be happier if you created your transformation in this order:

```
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0.5, 1);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
af.concatenate(new AffineTransform(w, 0, 0, h, 20, 20));
```

PS: As Tilman said: *Remember that the rotation is around the bottom-left*, so this composition will rotate off-screen, too. Simply add `h+20` to the x coordinate of the initial translation.

Comment: Ah ok, I did indeed think translation was adding the values.  As mentioned in Tilman's reply, I've solved it now - I used his answer, but had to swap the height and width.  But you have also been very helpful for the matrix info, thanks.